# Segment only horizontal plane (0*x+0*y+1*z+D=0) from point-cloud using RANSAC and pcl::SACSegmentation

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, ransac

I would like to extract the horizontal plane from the pointcloud using PCL library. There is a known procedure to extract planes using RANSAC that would find the largest plane, however I would like to constrain search to only horizontal planes (A*x+B*y+C*z+D=0, where A,B=0 and C=1).
Following code was an attempt to implement that by adding Axis vector, along z-axis (0,0,1) and EpsAngle tolerance to the SACSegmentation object.

However it does not seem to work the way I expect and it looks as setting Axis vector with setAxis() is not affecting the inlier plane at all, I keep on getting side planes from the neighboring walls rather than floor (horizontal) plane, or plane oriented along specified axis.

Pointcloud is such that there are 4 walls (hence 4 planes) and a floor that also should result with a fifth plane.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr pointcloudIn(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
// Segment the ground
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr         plane (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr              inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
plane->values.resize(4);            // Make room for a plane equation (ax+by+cz+d=0)

pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ>  seg;   // Create the segmentation object
seg.setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f(0., 0., 1.));   // Set the axis along which we need to search for a model perpendicular to
seg.setEpsAngle((10.*M_PI)/180.);           // Set maximum allowed difference between the model normal and the given axis in radians
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients(true);          // Coefficient refinement is required
seg.setMethodType(pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
seg.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
seg.setDistanceThreshold(0.05f);
seg.setInputCloud(pointcloudIn);
seg.segment(*inliers, *plane);

// Extract inliers
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
extract.setInputCloud(pointcloudIn);
extract.setIndices(inliers);
extract.setNegative(false);             // Extract the inliers
extract.filter(*pointcloudPlane);       // pointcloudPlane contains the plane
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SACMODEL_PARALLEL_PLANE` instead of `SACMODEL_PLANE` together with `setAxis`.
Use the `Z`-Axis as the axis, so `setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ())`.

You should also consider using `setEpsAngle()` to not limit yourself to perfect planes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to detect a horizontal surface using SACMODEL_PARALLEL_PLANE, and setAxis(1, 0, 0).  This is strange but it works (I was expecting to provide 0, 0, 1).

Maybe it is a bug in pcl (I use 1.13).

Comment: actually it waw just sufficient to do

Well, it is sufficient to do following:

`planeDetectionSegmentation_.setModelType(pcl::SACMODEL_PERPENDICULAR_PLANE);
planeDetectionSegmentation_.setAxis(Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ());`